# Can not Install twitter AnomalyDetection package

Tags: r, twitter

This is the code I am using to install the package in R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03).

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("twitter/AnomalyDetection")
library(AnomalyDetection)
```

This is what I get when I attempt to install package AnomalyDetection.

```
Downloading GitHub repo twitter/AnomalyDetection@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/twitter/AnomalyDetection/zipball/master
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
```

Comment: I have the same R version (Mac) and it works for me. Also considering the error message it seems to be a problem with GitHub and not R.

Comment: Hi, elevendollar then what is your suggestion.

Comment: hi epo3 , I have tried with library Rcurl too. but i am getting same error.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I got my answar.

```
library(RCurl)
library(httr)
set_config( config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L ) )
if (!requireNamespace("devtools", quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("twitter/AnomalyDetection")
library(AnomalyDetection)
```